# Access DOM elements on HTML page loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

Im currently struggling with an AJAX related problem on a website.
The goal is as follows:
There is a "simple" HTML page containing some links and content.

If you click on a link I want to open the file that gets includes with the link (from href) within a new div overlayed to the page. The content from the page is of course loaded with AJAX into the new div (the overlayed one).

Within this new overlayed div I want to add some JS code which in general already works.
The problem anyway is that the DOM elements within the page loaded per AJAX cannot be accessed in a way that is comfortable to work with, in my specific case.
I got following piece of code so far:

```
$$('.add-exercise').addEvent('click', function(e) {
        var request_exercise_add = new Request.HTML({
            'method' : 'post',
            'url' : e.target.get('href'),

            onSuccess : function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript) {
            // i know i can access responseElements here..
            }
        });

        request_exercise_add.send('s=true');

        return false;
    });
```

I know I can access the elements returned within responseElements but the logic on the included website is somehow quite complex and therefore it should be 
possible to add the JS within the HTML code in the dynamically loaded page. 
Notice that the JS also cannot be added to the `head` section because it would not know the elements that are loaded after the dom-ready event.

Comment: was my answer related to your question? did I understood you right?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried iframe ?
or the website that you are trying to add does not have PPP cookie and AllowContentInIframe .. ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already thought about it and might give it a try but I`m still interested into a "basic" AJAX solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the script inside the ajax request you need `evalScripts: true` and you should remove the quotes around the [**request**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML) options.

```
$$('.add-exercise').addEvent('click', function (e) {
    var request_exercise_add = new Request.HTML({
        method: 'post',
        url: e.target.get('href'),
        evalScripts: true,
        onSuccess: function (responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript) {
            // i know i can access responseElements here..
        }
    });
    request_exercise_add.send('s=true');
    return false;
});
```

I don't know what is the content of the response but you might also want to use Mootools's  [**.set()**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:set) instead of `innerHTML` to append new elements (if you are not doing that yet). Maybe worth to check [**Dimitar**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126998/dimitar-christoff)'s answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115104/any-difference-between-innerhtml-and-sethtml-in-mootools)** about that.